# Django template: handling the href attribute as a conditional

Tags: django, django-templates

Right now in my Django template I'm writing a whole new `a` tag if the conditional passes or fails. Is there a way to write this conditional in the `a` tag so that there is only one a tag?

```
{% for app in apps %}
    {% if app.app_id == "app-smart" %} 
      <a href='{{app.url}}' class='portfolio-link'>
    {% else %}
      <a href='{% url app.url %}' class='portfolio-link'>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: well quite simply move the conditional into the href value part.

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply:

```
{% for app in apps %}
  <a href='{% if app.app_id == "app-smart" %}{{app.url}}{% else %}{% url app.url %}{% endif %}' class='portfolio-link'>
{% endfor %}
```

There's nothing magic in django templates, that's just plain text templating.